# TP Link TD-W8968 how to view data statistics based on ip

Tags: networking, router, dsl-modem

I have a tp link modem and multiple device connected to it. I want to see which device is eating up all the bandwidth and crossing my data limit. How can I see that?

I have my mobile phone, pc, laptop, tablet all connected to it. If I can see which device used how much bandwidth or total data, I can judge by that.
Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware version of your modem router is V3 where as you are checking the document of hardware V1. Please have a look on the [document of V3 hardware](http://www.tp-link.in/resources/document/TD-W8968_V3_User_Guide_1910010970.pdf). It seems that the feature is not available with hardware V3.

Comment: So, it seems that Indians are provided with a cut down version of the hardware and software to reduce the cost. :(

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I view data statistics on TP Link TD-W8968 router?

> **4.19.10 Statistics**
>
> Choose menu "System Tools" → "Statistics", and then you can view the
> statistics of the modem router, including total traffic and current
> traffic of the last Packets Statistic Interval.
>
> [image]
>
> **Statistics Status**:
>
> Enable or Disable. The default value is disabled. To enable it, click
> the Enable . If it is disabled, the function of DoS protection in
> Security settings will be disabled.
>
> **Statistics Interval (5-60)**:
>
> The default value is 10. Select a value between 5 and 60 seconds in
> the drop-down list. The Packets Statistic interval indicates the time
> section of the packets statistic.
>
> Click Reset All to reset the values of all the entries to zero.
>
> Click Delete All to delete all entries in the table.
>
> Click the Refresh button to refresh immediately.
>
> **Statistics Table**:
>
> [image]

Source [User Manual](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TD-W8968_V1_User_Guide.pdf), p94:

---

#### I am not able to find the menu "System Tools

> What I have is Device Info, Quick Setup, Operation Mode, Advance Setup, IPTV, Wireless, Guest Network, USB Settings, Diagnostics, Management, Logout."

Try looking "Device Info" > "Statistics" > "LAN"

Note:

- You may have firmware that is newer than the v1.0 in the linked user manual with a different menu layout.
- You may have firmware that is for a specific market or ISP that doesn't log this information.

Comment: I am not able to find the menu "System Tools". What I have is Device Info, Quick Setup, Operation Mode, Advance Setup, IPTV, Wireless, Guest Network, USB Settings, Diagnostics, Management, Logout. That's it.

Comment: @happyhardik Try looking under "Device Info" -> "Statistics" -> "Lan". See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, that one shows how much transferred through WLAN0 (Wireless), but doesn't show which device did it or which IP did it.

Comment: Firmware Version: 1.0.5 Build 140821 Rel.52209

Comment: <Shrug>. I've no idea why your TP Link TD-W8968 is so different compared to the manual. Are you sure about the model number?

Comment: Might be because I have an Indian version of it? The model is correct with ipv6 support and a usb port for printer and 3G modem.

Comment: Check out http://www.tp-link.in/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TD-W8968#down - it has later firmware and manuals

Comment: It seems I have the latest firmware: Firmware Version: 1.0.5 Build 140821 Rel.52209
Hardware Version: TD-W8968 V3 0x00000001

Comment: No more ideas, other than you could see if one of the alternate firmwares like openwrt or dd-wrt will have the stats you need.